# c++ output figuring out problems

Tags: c++, output, iostream

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int& p)
{
    p += 2;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    f(x);
    int y = x + 1;
    f(y);
    cout << "x is " << x << endl;
    cout << "y is " << y << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Now the answer is that `x` is 12 and `y` is 15.

I kind of understand maybe that `x` is 12. To explain if I got it right is that as

```
void f (int &p)
{
    p += 2;
}
```

and as `int x = 10` so you `10 += 2` which is 12 so `x` is 12.

But I don't quite understand why `y` is 15.

Is it because I use 12 as `x` for `int y = x + 1` so it's `12 + 1` which is 13 and then `13 += 2` which is 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because I use 12 as `x` for `int y = x + 1` so it's `12 + 1` which is 13 and then `13 += 2` which is 15?

Yes. `f` is a function that takes an integer value **by reference** and increments it by `2`. After the function call, the integer will be permanently changed.

```
int x = 10;
// `x` is 10.

f(x);
// `x` is now 12.

int y = x + 1;
// `y` is 13.

f(y);
// `y` is now 15.
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are changed inside `f()`, because they are sent *by reference* - `void f(int& p)`.

So:

```
int x = 10;
f(x);  // x is 12 after the call
int y = x + 1; // y = 13
f(y);  // y = (12+1) + 2 = 15 after the call
```

Updated question:

> Is it because I use 12 as x for int y = x + 1 so it's 12 + 1 which is
>   13 and then 13 += 2 which is 15?

Yes, see above.